# How visualize tbl_sql data using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm getting the error, `ggplot2 does not know how to deal with data of class tbl_sqlite/tbl_sql/tbl_lazy/tbl`. Does this mean I need to reduce the size of my data or convert it to another format before I can plot it?

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `collect` at the end of your `dplyr` database query to pull the data into a data frame prior to plotting in `ggplot2`

Comment: Thanks @JakeKaupp, that solves it. I'm going to leave this question here because I didn't find anything when I googled this error message and I'm guessing others will find it when searching.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dplyr` holds off on actually collecting the data into r until it is explicitly told to.  When using `dplyr` to query a database, be sure to use `collect` at the end of the chain to pull the query result into r as a data frame.

*addendum*: the [`dbplot`](https://github.com/edgararuiz/dbplot) package now provides helper functions to work with `dplyr` & `dbplyr` to do some plotting or calculations for intermediate plotting steps in-database